# Short footcites beyond the text

Tags: jurabib

I need help! How can I insert German footcites beyond the text with only author, year and pagenumber? I am using `jurabib` and the typical `\footcite` command and it gives me too big footcites with the whole title and everything in it...

Answer (score 4):

Use `\footcite` together with the `jureco` bibliography style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pages=format]{jurabib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  address = {(Address)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footcite[99]{A01}

\bibliographystyle{jureco}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]